# Get info programmatically about Messages (SMS) on iPhone using Monotouch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I am new in Mono / Monotouch and I just started developing for iPhone. As a heavily .Net developer I want to congratulate for a productive & simple & mature product.

How to get informations about messages (sms)? Do we have any "event" when iPhone will send / receive a message, if not how to to track this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access incoming SMS in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519252/access-incoming-sms-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

If MonoTouch is using public SDK APIs on a stock OS device, then there is (currently) no event or notification regarding SMS messages sent to any non-Apple apps.  So you don't get any information.

It's all part of Apple's security sandbox.